# search for first occurence of a string and print its value in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Hi i am using the below content in a file , i want the value of shortversion to be printed ,

```
{
    "app_versions": [
        {
            "version": "15",
            "shortversion": "0.0.15",
            "title": "java expert",
            "timestamp": 1469530069,
            "appsize": 3436229,
            "notes": ,
            "mandatory": false,
            "external": false,
            "device_family": null,
            "id": 9,
            "app_id": 356250,
            "minimum_os_version": "4.1",
            ,
            {
                "version": "7",
                "shortversion": "0.0.7",
                "title": "java expert",
                "timestamp": 1469528889,
                "appsize": 3436225,
                ,
                {
                    "version": "3",
                    "shortversion": "0.0.3",
                    "title": "javaExpert",
                    "timestamp": 1469209202,
                    "appsize": 3420965,
```

how can i print the value of first occurrence of short version using sed,i have used the following awk command to get the shortversion `awk -F'"' '/\"shortversion\"/{print $10;}'` read.version this command is generating output of `0.0.15` which is correct , but the file is getting generated dynamically , need your valuable help on this

Comment: please format your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why does it need to be with sed? Why does "the file is getting generated dynamically" matter? The awk script you posted will not produce the output you say it does given the input you posted - [edit] your question to be accurate and consistent within itself.

Comment: I think the edit should be reversed until and unless OP confirms that the input is indeed provided on separate lines. The original post implied that the input is provided on one long line (hence the use of `$10`).

Answer (score 0):

It is more modular to use a command line JSON parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse your JSON input. It would be easier to maintain your script in case your JSON object tree change in the future.

You can get `shortversion` for the first element of your `app_versions` array with the following  :

```
jq -r ". |  .app_versions[1].shortversion" your_file.json
```

Comment: Hi Martel , thanks for your time, can we get the same without using json parser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change a qualifier ':';eg
awk -F":" '/shortversion/{print $2}' datafile
and then use 'sed' to replace ','and '"';

Comment: idk what you're thinking with that but you never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything sed can do.

Comment: i think  I consider not comprehensive.  should be:                                    awk -F":" '/shortversion/{gsub(/"|,/,"",$2);print $2}' datafile                          
thank for you advice